# Insert data from one to another table is not working

Tags: mysql

I have  two mysql table t1 & t2

t1 has one field called 'name'

'
t2 has two field  called 'name' and 'date',  where 'date' field set as current **timestamp** in default

I need to import all data from t1 to t2

> INSERT into T2 SELECT * FROM  t1

query is not working, its saying that count of fields are not same

How can i modify this query?

Comment: `INSERT INTO T2 SELECT Name FROM t1` will this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

INSERT INTO t2 (NAME )SELECT Name FROM t1

Answer (score 0):

Insert into t2 select name from t1

Try and let me know

Comment: Getting an error ,Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Answer (score 0):

insert into t2 (name) (select name from t1)